# "Error creating directory: Read-only file system" - Can't copy files to Pendrive

Tags: usb-drive, read-only

When i am tring to copy the folders or files to pendrive, I got error message "Error creating directory: Read-only file system". I have tried to give permission to pendrive - chmod 777 * /media/"Name of Pendrive", but i am facing the same issue. I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Please check if the hardware switch on your pen drive is set to read-only. If not, check the last lines of `dmesg` just after inserting the pen drive.

Comment: If you are running 16.04, why did you tag 14.04 ?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /media`? Also how is pen drive formatted?

Comment: Try reformatting it - using the "disks" tool. If that doesn't work, usb sticks will go read-only when they get old - the flash chips are only good for a few hundred write cycles (usually), once they are too degraded to be usable, the drive will go read-only so you can still recover your data.

Comment: @SorenA After dmesg command, i got like as below [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk

Comment: @guiverc I have changed.

Comment: @PaulBenson output is ---> drwxr-xr-x 46 .... 16384 jan 1 1970 A265-D...

Comment: If a file-system is mounted as RO (read-only), you cannot `chmod` any permissions, as that requires write access.  Please don't reply in comments, edit your question & add additional information there.  Check `mount` to ensure it's mounted read-only, if you didn't intentionally mount that way (ie. you mounted it as read-write) then it's probably got errors requiring `fsck` (file system check) and to protect files on the device, the system switched RW to RO protecting data - logs will show this.

Comment: I have formatted pen drive and problem has been solved. Thank you all of you who helped me to solve this issue.